# Trying to find a specific instance of a class by number

Tags: jquery, arrays, class, instance

I guess I have just hit a mental block with this one; maybe some fresh eyes will help.

Basically I have a few instance of the class "menu-item" which when clicked call the click function via jQuery and bring up a video. Instead of giving each on an id as well as a class I am trying to find which instance of the class was clicked (1, 2, 3, etc). 
Just can't seem to get it though.

```
//click listener for menu-items
 $('.menu-item').click(function(event)
 {
      var o = $('.menu-item');
      var count = o.length();                    

     switch(count)
     {
      case 0 :
       filename == 'letters';
      break;
      case 1 :
       filename == 'the-gift';
      break;
     }

  var videoPlayer = '<video controls  width="618px">';
  videoPlayer += '<source src="_video/' + filename + '.mp4" />';
  videoPlayer += '</video>';

  //place video   
  $('#videoCont').html(videoPlayer);
 });
```

I'm trying to create an array there where each instance of the 'menu-item' is one array item.
(btw, for now I am just proofing this with an mp4 filetype before I add in the ogv and webm formats).

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: You sure you meant `kQuery` and not `jQuery`? LOL

Comment: What do you mean by *"which instance of the class was clicked"* Do you mean instance by index? Or is there something else that distinguishes it from other `menu-item` elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @p.campbell's solution. I'm not sure how your code is going to work.

`var o = $('.menu-item')`

will always return the same amount of items, namely the number of items with menu-item as the class. Why not set an attribute like filename to whatever the appropriate value is. Like so

```
<li class='menu-item' filename='letters'>Letters</li>
```

and then in your click handler you can do

```
var filename = $(this).attr('filename');
```

Comment: ah, yeah - that gets it done.
I used $(even.target) but yeah works like a charm.
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're not actually assigning a value to your variable `filename`. You're only comparing the value of the variable to the hardcoded strings, but not assigning that (true/false) back to anything.

Likely you were meaning this?

```
switch(count)
{
  case 0 :
    filename = 'letters';
    break;

  case 1 :
    filename = 'the-gift';
    break;
}
```

Comment: Good catch, but it didn't quite solve my problem. Yads idea of having the filename attribute worked out nicely. Thanks though!